# Read value from XML field in SQL Server 2014 table

Tags: sql-server

I have an xml field column in my dbo.T_Office table with the following data:

```
<Offices>
   <office>
      <Id>12345</Id>
   </Office>
</Offices>
```

How can I read the Id value?

Comment: [`value()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/xml/value-method-xml-data-type). The example given is almost an exact match for this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

xml Is case sensitive.  I had to change your < office>  tag to < Office>

```
 declare @xml xml = 
 '<Offices>
   <Office>
      <Id>12345</Id>
   </Office>
</Offices>'

Select ref.value('Id[1]','integer') as xmlId
From @xml.nodes('/Offices/Office') x(ref)
```